# is it possible to read a HTML source that produces a json output in icCube?

Tags: etl, iccube

I am trying to read the following output from a HTML source (source is updated each 30 minutes):

```
{"un":"Watt","tm":"2015-11-21T15:57:00","dt":60,"val":["  510","  504","  504","  498","  498","  498","  498","  498","  498","  492","  492","  504","  522","  522","  516","  528","  528","  534","  522","  522","  504","  498","  498","  486","  486","  540","  528","  528","  534","  528",null]}
```

but I can not get it to work.

Is it possible to somehow indicate that the result is a json file, or do I have to aks someone to create an ETL plugin for this?

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: When you say HTML source do you mean an HTTP source?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant HTTP Source (thank you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes indeed, you would need to create a [plugin](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/plugins_extensions/cube_datasources.php) for that purpose.

Comment: ok,clear. Not the answer I was hoping for. No free lunch here ;-)